# ffmpeg image conversion works for nokia conformation heic files but not iphone heic images

Tags: ffmpeg, image-conversion, heic

Below ffmpeg image conversion  works for nokia conformation heic files but not iphone heic images

ffmpeg -i c001.heic  -c:v mjpeg -frames:v 1 -pix_fmt rgb48 outs.jpg 
(works for nokia conformation files https://github.com/nokiatech/heif_conformance/tree/master/conformance_files 
but not iphone images )

For iphone images ,it throws the below exception
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000021bcaba9980] moov atom not found
image4.heic: Invalid data found when processing input

Is there anything I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this works on images but try this ffmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -i c001.heic -c:v mjpeg -frames:v 1 -pix_fmt rgb48  -movflags faststart outs.jpg`

The `-movflags faststart` argument moves the atom files to the start of the file. This has worked for me for MOV files from iPhone. If that doesn't work in transcoding straight to JPG, first copy the file like so:

`ffmpeg -i c001.heic -c:v mjpeg -frames:v 1 -pix_fmt rgb48 -movflags faststart c001_fixed.heic`

Then attempt your original command.

Comment: `-movflags faststart` isn't needed for JPG, so it will get ignored. It's an option for MP4 output. mjpeg doesn't support `-pix_fmt rgb48` so you can remove that (using this option will cause the mjpeg encoder to output yuvj444p which may not be widely supported). When outputting JPG you don't need to manually declare `-c:v mjpeg`.

Comment: Wow, that was a handy response. :) Thank you @llogan for the clarification.